# Convergence of an infinite sum involving Gauss' hypergeometric function

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, hypergeometric-function

Consider the infinite summation : 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left[1-\ _{2}F_{1}\left(1,-\frac{s}{n};1-\frac{s}{n};z^{n} \right ) \right ]$$
Where $_{2}F_{1}\left(a,b;c;z\right)$ is the Gauss' hypergeometric function, $|z|<1$, and $s \in \mathbb{C},\Re(s)>0$. This summation seems to converge except when $s$ is a positive integer. But i don't know how to prove it. By the same token, is there a closed form for this sum ?